# Missing SHA256.HashData method?

Tags: c#, .net-core, methods, static, namespaces

I have a .NET Core 3.1 project, and whenever I access the class `SHA256`, I only get `Create`, `Equals`, `ReferenceEquals`, as methods I can invoke, but that shouldn't be the case as noted [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/System/Security/Cryptography/SHA256.cs,2b805a540db3f023).

Am I missing a package of some sorts?

Comment: The [docs on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=netcore-3.1) show no `HashData` method, and neither does the [.NET Core source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography/SHA256.cs)

Comment: @MindSwipe are you sure about the [latter](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c0669313dd36189c6d3bf5c7d5e866284f98263c/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography/SHA256.cs#L37)? I used .NET Core reference source in my post as well.

Comment: Every time Microsoft releases a new version of net the security class get updated to use for the defaults settings the latest version of the security modes.  So if a 32 bit version was replaced with a 64 bit version the 64 version is in the new code and will not work with old code that used 32 bit.

Comment: Seems like `HashData` is new with .NET 5.0 (and as such, on the GitHub sources but not on source.dot.net) [NET 5.0 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=net-5.0), [NET 3.1 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashData` method add in dotnet 5 and don't exits in dotnetcore 3.1 you can find in `HashData` [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256.hashdata?view=net-6.0#:%7E:text=or%2032%20bytes.-,Applies%20to,-.NET%206%20and) part of Applies to

image of current Applies to

[image]